# cURL unable to interpret hostnames, proxy issue?

Tags: curl, get, jersey, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-get

When using cURL from my ubuntu machine to merely GET from a remote machine, I seem unable to resolve the hostname and just get a Proxy Issue - `The proxy has encountered an error (Error 21: Server Hostname Not Found)` when running:

`curl remotehostname`

However, I am able to ping both `remotehostname` and it's ip address, and using `curl` on just the ip address works fine, e.g. `curl 1.2.3.4`.

I even tried a java program that uses the `ApacheHttpClient` implementation of the Jersey `Client`, and that worked fine too.

Is there a particular reason why cURL is unable to interpret `remotehostname` when everything else seems able to? I imagine it is a proxy related issue but as far as I can tell my proxy is set up fine seeing as everything else seems to work, just not cURL.

Answer (score 0):

A little too late I guess, but I've had a similar issue and this worked for me:

```
curl -4 remotehostname
```

This option tells curl to resolve names to IPv4 addresses only.

Monitoring the packets with wireshark, I saw that curl was trying to resolve the hostname to an IPV6 address, which was not possible.

Hope it works for you too, good luck.